# updating nested documents in mongoDB(node.js)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**i am trying to update a value in the object of my embedded schema(comments schema) whose value i had previously stored 0 by default. i have tried all the ways to update but none of the stackoverflow answer worked.
my code is**

```
var checkedBox = req.body.checkbox;       
User.updateOne({_id: foundUser._id},{$set :{comments:{_id :checkedBox,cpermission:1,}}},function(err,updatec){
          if(err){
            console.log(err);
          }
          else{
            console.log("successfull");
      console.log(updatec);

          }
        });
```

i had comment schema nested in user schema,here foundUser._id is the particular users id,and checkedBox id is the embedded objects particular id. previously my cpermission was 0,set by default,but now i want to update it to 1. although this is updating my schema,but deleting the previous images and comments in the schema aswell.
where am i going wrong?

**here is my schema**

```
const commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  comment: String,
  imagename: String,
    cpermission:{type:Number,default:0},
});

const Comment = new mongoose.model("Comment", commentSchema);

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstname: String,
  lastname: String,
  email: String,
  password: String,
  comments: [commentSchema],
  upermission:{type:Number,default:0},
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

Comment: You want commets cpermission to be 1, in all the comments where it was 0 before, is that  right?

Comment: yeah,but not for all,but only for the id's i pass through checkedBox

Comment: checkedBox  is an array of ids?

Comment: yes,its an array of id's

Comment: I have submitted an answer please check, if it doesn't solve your problem, please tell me in comment

Comment: yes thats working great! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to convert checkbox in the array, as it will be a string if you select a single element

Then wrap it with mongoose.Types.ObjectId as a precaution

Then you can use arrayFilters to update multiple matching array elements

```
var checkedBox = req.body.checkbox;
if (!Array.isArray(checkedBox)) {
   checkedBox = [checkedBox]
}

checkedBox = checkedBox.map(id => mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id))

User.updateOne(
    { _id: foundUser._id }, // filter part
    { $set: { 'comments.$[comment].cpermission': 1 } }, // update part
    { arrayFilters: [{ 'comment._id': {$in: checkedBox }}] }, // options part
    function (err, updatec) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log("successfull");
            console.log(updatec);

        }
    });
```

Comment: yes this is what i was looking for. working fine,thanks alot.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

your comment is the array of documents. if you want to update an element of an array must be select it. for that must be added another condition to the first section of `updateOne` then in seconde section use `$` for update selected element of the array.

```
User.updateOne(
        {_id: foundUser._id, 'comments._id': checkedBox},
        {
            $set: {'comments.$.cpermission': 1}
        }
        , function (err, updatec) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
            else {
                console.log('successfull')
                console.log(updatec)
            }
        })
```

for more information, you can read this document form MongoDB official website.
[Array Update Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update-array/)

Comment: it's not your answer? why do you remove the answer flag?

Comment: its only updating the first passed element,not all elements of the array whose id is passes through checkedBox

Comment: that's true. but your condition is on the `_id` field and that is unique in the comments list then its find one comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var checkedBox = req.body.checkbox;

  User.updateOne(
  { _id: foundUser._id, "comment._id": checkedBox },
  { $set: { "comment.$.cpermission": 1 } },
  function (err, update) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log("successfull");
    console.log(update);
  }
 }
 );
```

Comment: this will update the first element in the array, not a specific element with some condition ... `the positional $ operator acts as a placeholder for the first element that matches the query document`, you can check the docs for all the array update operators here 
 https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update-array/

Comment: @MohammedYousry in documentation tell `Acts as a placeholder to update the first element that matches the query condition.` if you add a correct condition that's work true.

Comment: if we have some comments array with this order in db `[commentI1, comment2, comment3]`, and you want to update `comment3`, and you passed `{ _id: foundUser._id, "comment._id": comment3 }` as a filter, you will get the document with the whole array, then update the first element in the array which is comment1, not comment3